# Changing the interval time when one of the states' value is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
someFunction() {    
     //........ some stuff

     else {
         const getData = setInterval(() => {
         this.sendRequest(id);

         if (this.state.calls === this.state.selectedItems.length) {
             this.setState({ done: true });
             clearInterval(getData);
            }
         }, this.changeInterval());
     }
},


changeInterval() {
      if(this.state.processed === true) {
            return 1000;
      } else {
            return parseInt(this.state.userSetValue, 10) * 1000 + 1000;
      } 
},

sendRequest(){
    //........ some stuff

    let {calls, processed} = this.state;
    if(!processed){
        processed = true;
    }
    calls++;

    this.setState({calls, processed});

    //........ some stuff
}
```

As i understand, the `setInverval()` function doesn't check its time interval whether it has changed or not after running function `this.sendRequest(id)`.

My problem is that I have to run `sendRequest()` after waiting some time, and that some time can be changed dynamically in my app. Currently, it only runs in an interval when it's **FIRST** set.

How could I change the interval of `setInterval()` each time `this.sendRequest(id)` is executed ?

**UPDATE**

I've made some changes to `someFunction()`:

```
someFunction() {
    //........ some stuff 
    else {
        let delay = parseInt(this.state.userSetValue, 10) * 1000 + 1000;
        let runFunction = () => {
                if (this.state.processed) {
                    delay = 1000;
                }
                // if (this.state.calls === this.state.selectedItems.length) {
                //     this.setState({ done: true });
                //     clearTimeout(runFunction);
                // }

                this.sendRequest();
                setTimeout(runFunction, delay);
            }
            setTimeout(runFunction, delay);
    }
}
```

The problem with this now is:

**1)** The code keeps running infinitely without stopping (the commented out `if` statement didn't make it stop)

**2)** I'd like the very first call to `this.sendRequest()` get executed after `parseInt(this.state.userSetValue, 10) * 1000 + 1000` time and the rest consecutive calls executed after `1000` ms.

I have to call the `this.sendRequest()` `this.state.selectedItems.length` number of times. The very first call always has a delay of`parseInt(this.state.userSetValue, 10) * 1000 + 1000` ms while the rest have `1000` ms.

Could anyone show an example how to change the timer interval after the first calling some function ?

Comment: Are you doing a ajax call?

Comment: My apis are done with `axios`

Comment: Use the promises, as it also Supports the Promise API

Comment: @MandeepSingh axios is promise based.  What exactly is the issue? I know your call isn't running at an interval but if you're changing the interval EVERY interval then you should be calling setTimeout. If you need it to happen in response to state change you can always put it in Will/DidMount

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak, basically i have to call `this.sendRequest(id)` `this.state.selectedItems.length - 1` amount of times, and the time interval changes (should change) after each call. How could `setTimeout()` help in this case? Having a loop and then calling `setTimeout` wouldn't work i think

Answer (score 0):

One of way of doing it would be to use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`. The basic ideas is as follows:

```
function doWork() {
  // Do your work here

  // Schedule more work with a new delay
  var newDelay = 2000;
  doWorkAfterDelay(newDelay)
}

function doWorkAfterDelay(delay) {
  setInterval(doWork, delay)
}

var intialDelay = 1000;
doWorkAfterDelay(intialDelay);
```